# Updating Form.intial does not change intial value in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

## Goal

I want to retain the query when a search result renders. [Here is an example where the search bar contains `stackoverflow` on the results page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etB3j.png)

## Failed Solutions

These are minimal code examples

```html
# search_results.html
<form action="/search" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

```py
# views.py
...
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    """Search view"""
    def form_valid(self, form):
        """redirect to the success url with url params"""
        quoted_user_query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(form.cleaned_data['user_query'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(''.join([self.get_success_url(), quoted_user_query]))

    def get_context_data(self. **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(**kwargs)
        user_query = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
        form.initial = {'user_query': user_query}
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        """append success url with search query"""
        if not self.success_url:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('No success url for {}'.format((str(self))))
        return ''.join([str(self.success_url), '?q='])
```

The first time I search in the browser, the template renders as expected. If I search `foo` the following is rendered

```html
<form action="/search" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="foo" name="search">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

But searching a second time doesn't change the string in the search bar. If I search `bar` after searching `foo`, the search bar's value does NOT change to `bar` as expected.

```html
<form action="/search" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="foo" name="search">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong? Below is the form code.

```py
# forms.py
from django import forms


class SearchBar(forms.Form):
    user_query = forms.CharField()
```

**EDIT:** 
When I added {{ form.initial.user_query }} to the template, the expected value renders as text next to the search bar, but does NOT render in the search bar.

```
# search_results.html
{{ form.initial.user_query }}
<form action="/search" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

```html
bar
<form action="/search" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="foo" name="search">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are getting any value with `self.request.GET.get('q', None)`, because name of the input field is `user_query` in the forms. So try like this:

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    """Search view"""
    def get_context_data(self. **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(**kwargs)
        user_query = self.request.GET.get('user_query', None)
        context['form'] = SearchBar(initial = {'user_query': user_query})
        return context
```

Also change the form method from post to get ie `<form method='get' action='/search'>`

Comment: I append `?q=<search query>` to the redirect url after a form validates. I've updated my question with the relevant code

Comment: while changing the method to GET is probably correct, it did not resolve the original problem

Answer (score 0):

I found a clunky solution that creates a new instance of the form instead of updating the `initial` attribute

```py
# views.py
...
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    """Search view"""
extra_context = {'form': SearchBar()}

    def get_context_data(self. **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(**kwargs)
        user_query = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
        if user_query is not None:
            context['form'] = self.form_class(data={'user_query': user_query})
        return context
...
```